# How do I prevent InAppBrowser from auto running with AngularJS $route?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

My app is running Cordova with AngularJS routing. I need the InAppBrowser plugin to view pdfs. However, since ngroute calls an html on a route change InAppBrowser is called.

I only need it to run on button click not everytime.

-- edit --

When I have the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin installed I get a white screen and a message regarding a white list issue regarding my inital route "index.html":

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', { //load home at start
    controller: 'HomeController as homeSlides',
    templateUrl: 'content/home.html',
    resolve: {
        // I will cause a 1 second delay
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
            var dl = document.getElementById('door-left');
            var dr = document.getElementById('door-right');
            dl.classList.remove('open');
            dr.classList.remove('open');
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

If I uninstall the plugin the issue is resolved.

-- edit --
This is the error I'm getting:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
[object Object]
APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://25052ninjadrew.nanosales/www/[object Object] because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.
APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to ms-appx://25052ninjadrew.nanosales/www/[object Object] because of this error: 80004005.
new transaction is waiting for open operation
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
[object Object] (1,1)
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
index.html
```

-- edit --

For client reasons I can't show too much of my html but...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nanoApp" class="test">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <script src="js/min/iscroll-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngroute.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/database.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-script.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="{{bodyclass}}">

    <div id="door-left" style="background-image:url('img/trans-left.png');" class="loading door-left" ></div>
    <div id="door-right"style="background-image:url('img/trans-right.png');" class="loading door-right" ></div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><span id="menu-cls" class="ion-close-round"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#/"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/products"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Installations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations/videos"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations/favorites"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/marketing"><div class="ion-grid"></div>Marketing Materials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="head">
        <div id="left-head">
            <div id="menu-btn"></div>
            <img src="img/header-left-x2.png" />
            <div class="filler"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle-head">
            <a style="display:block;" href="#/"><div id="logo"></div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="right-head">
            <img src="img/header-right-x2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="swipe-indicator"><span class="ion-chevron-left three"></span><span class="ion-chevron-left two"></span><span class="ion-chevron-left one"></span> Swipe <span class="ion-chevron-right one"></span><span class="ion-chevron-right two"></span><span class="ion-chevron-right three"></span></div>
    </div>


    <div id="content" class="scroller" ng-view>



    </div>


    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="footer-btns">
            <li><a href="#/products/" class="products"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations/" class="installations"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations/videos" class="videos"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/installations/favorites" class="favorites"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="filler"></div>
        <img src="img/bottom-bar-x2.png" class="bottom-bar" />
    </div>

    <!-- gallery popup -->
    <div id="gallery-container" ng-show="openGallery">
        <div class="ion-close-round close-gallery" ng-click="closeGallery()"></div>
        <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow" ng-click="prevSlide()" ng-show="galleryCount > 1"></div>

        <div id="slide-container">
            <div id="slides">
                <div class="slide" ng-repeat="slide in gallery" ng-switch on="galleryType" video-setup>
                    <!-- image template-->
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.file}}" ng-switch-when="image" />

                    <!-- video template-->
                    <video class="video" style="width:845px;height:635px;" controls autoplay ng-switch-when="video">
                        <source ng-src="{{slide.file}}" type='video/mp4' />
                    </video>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="slide-marker-container" ng-show="galleryCount > 1">
            <ul id="slide-markers">
                <li ng-repeat="marker in galleryMarkers(galleryCount) track by $index" marker-setup>
                    <div ng-click="scrollToSlide({{$index}})"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow" ng-click="nextSlide()" ng-show="galleryCount > 1"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

home.html:

```
<div id="home" set-iscroll home-setup class="container paralax">

            <a href="#/productslist/0" class="section">

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-home-bkg.jpg');" class="bkg"></div>

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-title.png');" class="element layer1" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>                
                <div id="slim-holt-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-holt-top.png');" class="element title" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div></div>
                <div id="slim-lv-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-lv-top.png');" class="element layer2" data-stellar-ratio="1.7" data-stellar-ratio="2"></div></div>
                <div id="slim-mel-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-mel-top.png');" class="element layer3" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div></div>
                <div id="slim-avyve-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slim-avyve-top.png');" class="element layer4" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div></div>

</a>

            <a href="#/productslist/1" class="section">

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/curve-home-bkg.jpg');" class="bkg"></div>

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/curve-title.png');" class="element title" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
                <div id="curve-aig-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/curve-aig-top.png');" class="element layer1" data-stellar-ratio="1.7"></div></div>
                <div id="curve-illy-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/curve-illy-top.png');" class="element layer2" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-ratio="2"></div></div>
                <div id="curve-minn-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/curve-minn-top.png');" class="element layer3" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div></div>

            </a>


            <a href="#/productslist/2" class="section">

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/clear-home-bkg.jpg');" class="bkg"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/clear-title.png');" class="element title" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
                <div id="clear-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/clear-top.png');" class="element layer1" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"></div></div>

</a>

            <a href="#/productslist/3" class="section">

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/wrap-home-bkg.jpg');" class="bkg"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/wrap-title.png');" class="element title" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
                <div id="wrap-eaton-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/wrap-eaton-top.png');" class="element layer2" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div></div>
                <div id="wrap-gte-top" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/wrap-gte-top.png');" class="element layer3" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"></div></div>

            </a>


            <a href="#/productslist/4" class="section">

                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/slimengage-home-bkg.jpg');" class="bkg"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url('img/home/slimengage-title.png');" class="element title" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
                <div id="slimengage-screen" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slimengage-screen.png');" class="element layer1" data-stellar-ratio="1.1"></div></div>
                <div id="slimengage-blueppl" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slimengage-blueppl.png');" class="element layer2" data-stellar-ratio="1"></div></div>
                <div id="slimengage-colorppl" class="indicator"><div style="background-image:url('img/home/slimengage-colorppl.png');" class="element layer3" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"></div></div>



            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: the router doesn't reload the entire page every time you change pages, that's the whole point of a SPA.  please post an example of what is happening with code so we can see what might cause the behavior you are describing.

Comment: I edited the the question. I'm not doing anything with InAppBrowser as of yet. Just testing the app loads without issue after the plugin is added. The plugin throws an error for my initial route of the home screen "index.html".

Comment: I also added the error for reference

Comment: where is the HTML?  the code you posted for `$routeProvider` isn't relevant, it has nothing to do with InAppBrowser at all, other than the fact that it handles the loading of that page.

Comment: There's no html to show. I've loaded the plugin via `cordova plugin add` that's all. I have an index.html that acts as my "frame" and `<div id="content" class="scroller" ng-view></div>` that loads content based on my route.

Comment: ok, so show the code of the `index.html` and the code of the `home.html` template; they can't be completely empty, and they would definitely show how/where you are initializing this plugin.... this routing code doesn't demonstrate anything.

Comment: The plugin is included as a package upon build out. I don't load it via a `script` tag. The plugin hooks into `window.open` which is apparently called when the route is called.

Comment: no, that's not correct at all.  something else is going on, but if you won't provide anything that can be used to reproduce the issue, it's not really possible to know what that something else is.

Comment: just reading about the plugin you are using, at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, "For backwards compatibility, this plugin also hooks  window.open . However, the plugin-installed hook of  window.open  can have unintended side effects (especially if this plugin is included only as a dependency of another plugin). The hook of  window.open  will be removed in a future major release. Until the hook is removed from the plugin, apps can manually restore the default behaviour:
`delete window.open // Reverts the call back to it's prototype's default`"

Comment: maybe that will solve your issue.

Comment: I've provided all the html for both. If I remove the plugin from cordova my issue goes away. When I install it, the issue returns.

Comment: I tried the `delete window.open` fix but it didn't have any affect. I placed it before my angular app was declared in my js file. I even tried it before any js was loaded, nothing.

Comment: the `delete window.open` command would need to be in the `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {` so that it would delete the `window.open` hook *after* the plugin has initialized.  the hook doesn't exist yet until that state.

Comment: this might actually mean you may have to manually bootstrap angular as well;

Comment: That's how I initialized `delete window.open` I tried in `angular-script.js` and before any of the `js` files

Comment: I'm going to experiment a bit and see what I can dig up; however, I think I may know what the issue is.

Comment: are you using HTML5Mode in your app? and if so, does the error go away if you go back to the standard hash mode?  I suspect that the InAppBrowser plugin doesn't support the HTML5 History API.

Comment: The whole purpose is to open local PDF files (groan)

Comment: actually I looked at your index, you aren't using HTML5Mode, so there must be something else going on

Comment: the line `The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://25052ninjadrew.nanosales/www/[object Object]` in the error is troubling, it's like it is looking for a resource and doesn't know how to convert the object (whatever it is) into a query string.

Comment: I'm just using Angularjs Routing. The only time I need to use InAppBrowser is when specified links are clicked initiated by an `ng-click` inside a `directive`.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but I don't really think that's how the plugin is designed.  it's marketed as "a drop in replacement for window.open()`, which tells me that it's replacing the actual browser window, it's not hosted on your page, it's replacing your page.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to do at this point to be honest